# /grub/i386-pc/normal.mod not found with special condition

Tags: linux, grub, boot-loader

I updated my ubuntu server from 18.04 to 20.04 and reboot. after reboot I fall in grub rescue. in the (hd0,gpt2) there are some directories include grub. in grub there is i386-pc and in the i386-pc all grub module, include normal.mod exist. but all the files has a '-' as their last characters. so when I type insmod normal, it gives me error that file not found.
how can I solve the problem?[image]